# Jest mock working with require and not working with import in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am using jest mock in typescript I am getting error while importing but everything working fine while using require.
this is not working.

```
import {useNewApplicationStatus,IHeaderWithItems} from "../useNewApplicationsStatus";

useNewApplicationStatus = jest.fn(
  (): IHeaderWithItems => {
    return initState;
  }
);
```

but this is working

````
const useNewApplication = require("../useNewApplicationsStatus");

useNewApplication.useNewApplicationStatus = jest.fn(
  (): IHeaderWithItems => {
    return initState;
  }
);```
````

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you take look at my specific question I have tried all that but it isn't working

Comment: @jonrshape I'm getting you cannot mutate

Comment: @adreds I have read somewhere you have written that you were getting cannot mutate error I'm getting the same error what's the solution